# Installing PerlMagick7 on Windows Strawberry Perl

Tags: windows, perl, imagemagick

I'm trying to install perl module Image::Magick (version 7.0.11) on Windows 10 with Strawberry perl 5.32. I have read and tried many of the things suggested that I found online however none is recent and none has worked for me.
I've installed ImageMagick-7.1.0-9-Q8-x64-dll (checked 'adding paths' and 'include header files'). Seems there is still a problem with finding the right files. `cpan Image::Magick` always errors out with

```
gcc -c   -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPER
L_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O
2   -DVERSION=\"7.0.11\" -DXS_VERSION=\"7.0.11\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"  -D_LARGE_FILES=1 -DH
AVE_CONFIG_H Magick.c
Magick.xs:56:10: fatal error: MagickCore/MagickCore.h: No such file or directory
 #include <MagickCore/MagickCore.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing required header file `MagickCore/MagickCore.h` which is not available on your system (if it is available then you need to include it into the compilation by specifying `-I {path}` to the file). Perhaps you have to compile `ImageMagic` in MS Windows to make the package available. If you  would be in a Debian based Linux instead MS Windows, then `apt install libmagickcore-6-headers` would install required header files.

Comment: The header is present (in the folder where ImageMagick installed itself). The build of the Image::Magick module is controlled from the cpan tool and there is not much to influence there.

Comment: Please see the following [post](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=33788) if it is any help in your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Makefile.PL`](https://metacpan.org/release/JCRISTY/Image-Magick-7.0.11-1/source/Makefile.PL) uses the tools `identify.exe` or `convert.exe` to determine the location of the header files. If you did not install those tools it cannot find the headers.

You need to check the checkbox *"Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert)"* when running the setup program `ImageMagick-7.1.0-9-Q8-x64-dll.exe` ImageMagick:

[image]